# Find string in array inside array of objects

Tags: arrays, string, javascript-objects, lodash

I have a complex declarative config array of objects and i need to get some data from it.
this is my array:

```js
units = [{
    'hpid': '787',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Apartamento Solverde',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': [],
      'PRODUCT': [],
      'SEARCH': [],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '130',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Algarve Casino',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': ['/hotel-algarve-casino/'],
      'PRODUCT': [
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-standard-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-superior-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-familiar-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/suite-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/suite-vista-mar/',
      ],
      'SEARCH': [
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/',
        '/en/hotel-algarve-casino/rooms/'
      ],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '300',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Casino Chaves',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': ['/hotel-casino-chaves/'],
      'PRODUCT': [
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-standard-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-superior-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-familiar-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/suite-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/suite-vista-mar/',
      ],
      'SEARCH': [
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/',
        '/en/hotel-casino-chaves/rooms/'
      ],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '759',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Solverde Spa and Wellness Center',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': [],
      'PRODUCT': [],
      'SEARCH': [],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }
];
```

and need to find the atribute name that contains the string ex:`/en/hotel-casino-chaves/rooms/`

Also i need the value of 'hpid' attribute of the previous search.

I apreciate your help.
Thanks.

then i need to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

In the callback of [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) check if for the current element `c` one or more of the arrays in `c.pt` contain the search string.

If yes, add the `c.hpid` and the name of the properties containing the search string to the result.

```js
units = [{
    'hpid': '787',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Apartamento Solverde',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': [],
      'PRODUCT': [],
      'SEARCH': [],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '130',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Algarve Casino',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': ['/hotel-algarve-casino/'],
      'PRODUCT': [
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-standard-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-superior-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/quarto-familiar-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/suite-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/suite-vista-mar/',
      ],
      'SEARCH': [
        '/hotel-algarve-casino/quartos/',
        '/en/hotel-algarve-casino/rooms/'
      ],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '300',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Casino Chaves',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': ['/hotel-casino-chaves/'],
      'PRODUCT': [
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-standard-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-superior-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/quarto-familiar-vista-mar/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/suite-vista-avenida/',
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/suite-vista-mar/',
      ],
      'SEARCH': [
        '/hotel-casino-chaves/quartos/',
        '/en/hotel-casino-chaves/rooms/'
      ],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }, {
    'hpid': '759',
    'hpr': 'Hotel Solverde Spa and Wellness Center',
    'pt': {
      'CONVERSION': [],
      'HOME_PAGE': [],
      'PRODUCT': [],
      'SEARCH': [],
      'SHOPPING_CART': [],
      'TRACKING': []
    }
  }
];


let result = units.reduce((a,c) => {
  let entries = Object.entries(c.pt)
    .filter(y => y[1].includes('/en/hotel-casino-chaves/rooms/'));
    
  for (let e of entries) {
    a.push({ hpid: c.hpid, prop: e[0]});
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```